# Dynamically increasing the size of a div tag in C#/Javascript based on its child control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a div tag in which i have an autogrow textarea. When I press any key or type something within the textarea, its height increases one line at a time. But the problem here is that the size of the div tag is the same, so that looks too bad, like the textarea falling out from the div container...
So I want the div tag to also expand simultaneously as the textarea increases.
The code below represents the code for the textarea contained within a div tag

```
<body bgcolor="#CCC" style="height: 460px">
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
<div  id="expandable_div" style="background-color: #000000" >
    <textarea id="Text1"  rows = "8" runat="server" cols="30" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)"   name="S1"> </textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

In the style sheet, I tried putting:

```
 div#expandable_div
        {
            min-height:205px;
            height:auto;
        }
```

Comment: Side note: You question is not an example of a good question. Please try to provide small fragments of HTML and CSS (5-10 lines should be more than enough for this question).

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` should expand automatically. I guess that the problem is that you're fixing the height of `div`. Let's say...

```
 height:205px;
```

Replace it with

```
min-height:205px;
min-width:300px;
```

Working Demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gErSX/1/)

Comment: @AnujKaithwas remove the `height:auto; ` from your css.. and then try

Comment: @AnujKaithwas Also do not fix the height of `body`. Set also the` min-height` of body..

Comment: :I am sorry but I  did not quite get your example, it is a normal code encasing a textarea in a div tag...

Answer (score 0):

Size of unstyled DIV is defined by its content. So either remove height style from DIV or adjust it dynamically based on size of textarea.